# How can we set classes for first time in mainnframe? As first time settings

Tags: jcl

I keep getting error as "Inactive printer - class=A" , on my new private mainframe.
I tried different class names , but nothing works. I guess I need to do some initial settings for classes. How can it be done?

Comment: what do mean "on my new private mainframe"?

Comment: Can you include the message your getting ($HASPnnnn I suspect).  Also, why is inactive bad?  What is the actual problem you’re having.  Something is not printing that your expecting to print ?